# Web site resolution fix for all resolution in Javascript

Tags: javascript, screen-resolution

I am using template where java script file has been used for fix resolution for all resolution. But I don't know javascript and if I make any changes in tempalate so resolution doesnt work.

```
    var ElementMaxHeight = function() {
      this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    ElementMaxHeight.prototype = {
      initialize: function(className) {
        this.elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className || 'maxheight');    
        this.textElement = document.createElement('span');
        this.textElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode('A'));
        this.textElement.style.display = 'block';
        this.textElement.style.position = 'absolute';
        this.textElement.style.fontSize = '1em';
        this.textElement.style.top = '-1000px';
        this.textElement.style.left = '-1000px';
        document.body.appendChild(this.textElement);
        this.textElementHeight = document.getDimensions(this.textElement).height;
        var __object = this;
        var __checkFontSize = this.checkFontSize;
        this.checkFontSizeInterval = window.setInterval(function() {return __checkFontSize.apply(__object)}, 500);

        this.expand();
    // Refresh elements height onResize event
    var __expand = this.expand;
    if (window.addEventListener) {
      window.addEventListener('resize', function(event) {return __expand.apply(__object, [( event || window.event)])}, false);
    } else if (window.attachEvent) {
      window.attachEvent('onresize', function(event) {return __expand.apply(__object, [( event || window.event)])});
    }
  },
      expand: function() {
        this.reset();
       for (var i = 0; i < this.elements.length; i++) {   
          this.elements[i].style.height = document.getDimensions(this.elements[i].parentNode).height + 'px';
       }
      },

      reset: function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.elements.length; i++) {    
          this.elements[i].style.height = 'auto';
        }
      },

      checkFontSize: function() {
       var height = document.getDimensions(this.textElement).height;
       if(this.textElementHeight != height) {
        this.textElementHeight = height;
        this.expand();
       }
      }  
    }


    if (!!document.evaluate) {
      document._getElementsByXPath = function(expression, parentElement) {
        var results = [];
        var query = document.evaluate(expression, parentElement || document,
          null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
        for (var i = 0, length = query.snapshotLength; i < length; i++)
          results.push(query.snapshotItem(i));
        return results;
      }
    }

    document.getElementsByClassName = function(className, parentElement) {
      if (!!document.evaluate) {
        var q = ".//*[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' " + className + " ')]";
        return document._getElementsByXPath(q, parentElement);
      } else {
        var children = (parentElement || document.body).getElementsByTagName('*');
        var elements = [], child;
        for (var i = 0, length = children.length; i < length; i++) {
          child = children[i];
          if (child.className.length != 0 &&
              (child.className == className ||
               child.className.match(new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + className + "(\\s|$)")))) {      
            elements.push(child);
          }
        }
        return elements;
      }
    }

    document.getDimensions = function (element) {
      var display = element.style.display;
      if (display != 'none' && display != null) { // Safari bug
        return {width: element.offsetWidth, height: element.offsetHeight};
      }

      return {width: originalWidth, height: originalHeight};
      var jswidth = screen.width;


    }
```

This is java script which used by template can any please help me how do I fix the screen resolution. How is this script working ?

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getDimensions = function (element) {
      var display = element.style.display;
      if (display != 'none' && display != null) { // Safari bug
        return {width: element.offsetWidth, height: element.offsetHeight};
      }

      return {width: originalWidth, height: originalHeight};
      var jswidth = screen.width;


    }
```

if you what to set a fix width and height just change the return value

From:

```
return {width: element.offsetWidth, height: element.offsetHeight};
```

To:

```
return {width: 800, height: 600};
```

From:

```
return {width: originalWidth, height: originalHeight};
```

To:

```
return {width: 800, height: 600};
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you write the complete action as it should be written in order to change resolution automatic ?

is it working for HTML & Flash ?